# woocommerce problem to make a product page responsive

Tags: css, woocommerce, styles, storefront

Hi and thanks in advance.
I have this NSFW site (romance eBooks with some hot images maybe)
https://sitetest.wigigx.com/mf-romance/

I managed to create a shortcode and a function to get an excerpt displayed next to the eBook cover Just in this page (of course via the created shortcode)
BUT the real  problem is that I can`t get the excerpt, price, title and star ratings centered and responsive and to fit the container so it align perfectly to the image size.

I managed to enter the excerpt, to "lift" the title )before was at the bottom) and to have some margin between image and text, but I need to

-Get the Title top centered

-Then the excerpt centered

-then the star rating

-finally the price

-and the Get it now bottun at the bottom All centered, aligned and responsive.

I also put some border to title to "see it" and edit ite

here the code so far, any idea?

```
/*Float image to the left*/
ul.products li.product img {
    float: left;
}

/*Add hover to image*/
a:hover img { 
    border:solid #eeccdd 5px;
}

/*Change Title color and float text to right*/
ul.products li.product .woocommerce-loop-product__title, ul.products li.product h2, ul.products li.product h3{
    color: #cc5588;
    float:right;
    width: auto;
}

/*Center Excerpt and price and Button Get it now*/
ul.products li.product{ text-align: center;
}


/*Lift Up title*/
.beta, h2 {
    clear: none;
    display: flex;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I had some advances, almost all solved except to put the Price at the bottom, for some reason the order do not work either CSS or PHP, keep trying

Answer (score 0):

great! I was able to solve it with some CSS

•   Changed float: left to title to display:inline-block

```
/*Change Title color and float text to left*/
ul.products li.product .woocommerce-loop-product__title, ul.products li.product h2, ul.productsli.product h3{
olor: #cc5588;
display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}
•   SOLVED added padding: 10px to image - make some space between image and text
/*Float image to the left*/
ul.products li.product img {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

thanks